# How to remove values from an object that don't match parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new to programming and am in a bit of a bind: I have an object that is an array, which has a value that is an array.

I'm able to print what's needed inside two for loops inside my HTML template with the help of [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) and filter() but I'm looking for a way to create an object or an array that has been somehow trimmed of the "unwanted" cars because I'm trying to send the data to the HTML template with res.render() and can't seem to do that inside or outside the for loops (either the program tries to render on every iteration of the for loop and causes an error, or the values inside the for loops seem to be out of scope?)

So I'm sending the persons variable to the template and then doing the for loops there on the client but I'd prefer to do the logic before sending to template to not clutter the template with JavaScript inside "scriplet" tags

```js
var myObj = [
  {
    "name": "Robert",
    "age": 40,
    "cars": [{
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Yaris",
        "year": 2010,
        "bought": "2012-11-1",
        "type": "lease"
      },
      {
        "make": "Peugeot",
        "model": "206",
        "year": 2005,
        "bought": "2017-05-11",
        "type": "lease"
      },
      {
        "make": "Volvo",
        "model": "V70",
        "year": 2019,
        "bought": "2020-07-02",
        "type": "owned"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 40,
    "cars": [{
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Corolla",
        "year": 2011,
        "bought": "2013-11-1",
        "type": "owned"
      },
      {
        "make": "Renault",
        "model": "Megane",
        "year": 2006,
        "bought": "2007-05-11",
        "type": "owned"
      },
      {
        "make": "Ford",
        "model": "Mondeo",
        "year": 2019,
        "bought": "2020-07-02",
        "type": "lease"
      }
    ]
  },
]

let persons = myObj.filter((person) => {
  return person.cars.some((car) => {
    return car.type == "lease"
  })
})
for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  for (y = 0; y < persons[i].cars.length; y++) {
    if (persons[i].cars[y].type === "lease") {
      console.log(persons[i].name)
      console.log(persons[i].cars[y].make)
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry if something similar has been asked a million times but I couldn't find anything similar enough to my problem and can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Can you more clearly define (1) what result you want, and (2) what's wrong w/what you're doing now?

Comment: The result I want is the whole myObj JSON object with only the cars that match the type === "lease" parameter but still want to keep the original JSON format and other values like the persons name and age if that makes sense.

The problem I'm having is that I must do the for looping in the html-template or client-side which is hard to read and if I need to use the values multiple times I must do the loops again adding redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you're indicating, the method below would give you an array of objects with the name of the person and the make of the leased cars:

```js
const personsCars = persons.map((person) => {
  const res = person.cars
    .filter((car) => car.type === 'lease')
    .map((car) => {
      return {name: person.name, make: car.make }
    });
  return res;
}).flat();

// Print array
personsCars.forEach((pc) => {
  console.log(pc.name, pc.make);
});
```

Comment: This code could be useful but I was more looking for a way to keep the original format of the JSON containing somehow just the values that match the parameter (type==="lease") if that's even possible. Row 1 persons-variable  probably needs to be myObj?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the structure of the JSON object you're envisioning?